# A border is adding to a HTML element's width (only on one side) for no reason I can see

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create this price column, and have been modifying the code of a tutorial, and everything was going fine until I added a border to .price section of it. The border added some extra width to the element, but only on the right side. I tried to see if another div was the reason, or some forgotten about margin/padding values with Chrome Dev Tools, but I can't see anything.

I would really appreciate any help with finding out what is causing the extra width to .price div

Here is the html:

```
  <ul class="pricing_table">
   <li></li>
   <li class="price_block">
      <h3>Web Development</h3>
      <div class="price">
         <div class="price_figure">
            <span class="price_number">$9.99</span>
            <span class="price_tenure">per month</span>
         </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="features">
         <li>2GB Storage</li>
         <li>5 Clients</li>
         <li>10 Active Projects</li>
         <li>Free Goodies</li>
         <li>24/7 Email support</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="buynow">
         <a href="#" class="action_button">Buy Now</a>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
* {
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style:none;
}

body {
font-family: roboto;
}

h3 {
  font-family: lato; 
}

.pricing_table {
line-height: 150%; 
font-size: 20px; 
margin: 0 auto; 
width: 75%;
max-width: 400px; 
padding-top: 10px;
margin-top: 100px;

}

.price_block, .price_block_blue {
width: 100%; 
color: black;
background-color: white;
float: left; 
list-style-type: none; 
transition: all 0.25s; 
position: relative; 
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-bottom: 10px; 

}

.pricing_table h3 {
text-transform: uppercase; 
padding: 5px 0; 
background: white; 
margin: -10px 0 0 0;
text-align: center;
border: 3px solid black;
border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
}

.price {
display: table; 
background: red; 
width: 100%; 
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 70px;
text-align: center;
border: 3px solid black;
border-top:0px solid black;
border-bottom:0px solid black;
}

.price_blue {
display: table; 
background: blue; 
width: 100%; 
height: 70px;
text-align: center;
}
.price_figure {
font-size: 24px; 
text-transform: uppercase; 
vertical-align: middle; 
display: table-cell;
}
.price_number {
font-weight: bold; 
padding: 10px 0 0 0; 
display: block;
}
.price_tenure {
font-size: 11px; 
}

.features {
background: #fff; 
color: #000;
text-align: center;
border: 3px solid black;
border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
border-top: 0px solid transparent;
}
.features li {
padding: 8px 15px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
font-size: 11px; 
list-style-type: none;
}

.buynow {
padding: 15px; 
background: white;
text-align: center;
border: 3px solid black;
border-top: 0px solid black;
}
.action_button {
text-decoration: none; 
color: white; 
font-weight: bold; 
border-radius: 5px; 
background: red; 
padding: 5px 20px; 
font-size: 11px; 
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.price_block:hover,.price_block_blue:hover {
box-shadow: 0 0 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
transform: scale(1.04) translateY(-5px); 
z-index: 1; 
border-bottom: 0 none;
}
.price_block:hover .price {
background: yellow; 
/*box-shadow: inset 0 0 45px 1px #ADD8E6;*/
}

.price_block_blue:hover .price_blue {
background: yellow; 

}
.price_block:hover h3{
background: black;
color: white;
}
.price_block_blue:hover h3 {
background: black;
color: white;
}

.price_block:hover .action_button, .price_block_blue:hover .action_button {
background: linear-gradient(#F9B84A, #DB7224); 
}
```

Comment: You can create an example of your code on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net). Do note that it is very hard to read all your code. So please try to narrow it to exactly the place you have a problem and share that part with us.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are adding a border, it gets added to your overall width. So the actual width of .price is 100% + 3px (left border) + 3px (right border). To have the total width include padding and borders, use box-sizing:

```
.price {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped, but now there is about 1px missing inside the element on the right side and only at full laptop screen (anything smaller and it goes away). Even though it shouldn't be affecting it I got rid of the media query styles that added an invisible border to the right side of the element, but the missing 1px is still there. I also still have no clue why it is only happening one side of the element, not the left and right.