# How to get a border around body tag without it cutting off?

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner who wants to visualize the html and css changes that I make while learning and so I would like to put a border around all the elements that I add.

Problem: The blue border around the html/body element cuts off and isn't fully displayed on the bottom and right sides of the border when overflow is set to hidden.

**Why is it that the border is overflowing the html page even when its width and height are set to 100%?**

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> Practice Webpage </title>
        <link href="stylesrevised.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    </head>

    <body></body>
    </html>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0; /* Space from this element (entire page) and others*/
    padding: 0; /*space from content and border*/
    border: solid blue;
    border-width: thin;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
}
```

[Here is the resulting webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpoCH.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A border is adding to a HTML element's width (only on one side) for no reason I can see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289089/a-border-is-adding-to-a-html-elements-width-only-on-one-side-for-no-reason-i)

Comment: I would recommend using `outline: 1px solid blue;` instead of `border`. Borders will not only affect the box model as answers below speak of, but can also prevent margin collapsing.

Comment: @Web_Designer, `outline` on `body` or `html` will be outside of the visible window and not displayed. If you want to see it, you'll need to use `outline-offset: -1px` to see it. Be sure to set the offset as a negative number of the outline width (i.e., `outline: 17px solid blue; outline-offset: -17px`)

Answer (score 8):

Welcome to the coding journey!!! In your css, add the following: `box-sizing: border-box;`

This will make your elements fit within the prescribed width and height.

```css
html,body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0; /* Space from this element (entire page) and others*/
    padding: 0; /*space from content and border*/
    border: solid blue;
    border-width: thin;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> Practice Webpage </title>
        <link href="stylesrevised.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    </head>

    <body></body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Got it working. Should I add this to all elements that I want to visualize? (divs, images, etc).

Comment: @Zach The answer to that question is - it depends. If you want to see your elements without padding and border thickness affecting the size of your elements, then yes. Try it out both ways - with it set and without it set.

In a development setting, you calculate the size of your elements by adding padding *2, border width *2, and margin*2 to the width/height to tell where they will be and their size. Even then, it depends on what you are trying to create.

If all you want is to visualize your elements, it doesn't hurt to use it every time.

Use `* { box-sizing: border-box;}`

Answer (score 1):

your `overflow: hidden;` is whats messing things up for you, the default setting for borders is content-box which adds pixels to the width and height of your elements, eg if you have a div 100px wide and add a 1px border to it is actual size will be 102px.

you can solve this by using `box-sizing: border-box;` which causes the border to be added to the inside of the element instead.

```css
html,body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0; /* Space from this element (entire page) and others*/
    padding: 0; /*space from content and border*/
    border: solid blue;
    border-width: thin;
    display:block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If you want to make this effect all borders used through out your site you can use this, saves having to set it each time you add a border.

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: @Zach i've updated my answer * will catch all future borders you add so you dont have to keep adding that code. Anything you want to have the blue border around you'll need to add the border: 1px solid blue; code